# Is there a ready made roles/membership framework for ASP.NET Web Forms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-membership, roleprovider

There were few questions related to this but none answered the question in my head. Suggestions included **Asp.net Membership system**, a **search on codeplex** foundation or **role out your own**. Rolling out my own would be last resort as it would involve testing and design time involved. All i want role provider to perform is restrict users permissions over a action. Below you can find a scenario for understanding it,

Think you are admin of a Forum/Discussion board of some sort and during installation of the software it created two membership for you something like

1. Gold member
2. Silver member

Here are some imaginary roles for these memberships,

**Gold member:**

Can edit Posts by others

Can create Polls

**Silver Member:**

Can report Posts to admin

Can ban members of lower membership value

all these above roles are bit fields for ease of validation based on roles. Now my question is ,

**Question**

Do you know any role provider that would give me fine grain of control like above where i can edit roles for a membership, create new membership and assign roles etc which would also integrate to SignUp time integration

**Specs:**
.NET 2.0 & Asp.net 2.0

Comment: Take a look at this implementation: http://blog.gauffin.org/2011/09/a-more-structured-membershipprovider/.

Comment: @Steven is this mvc? also does it work with Asp.net 2.0 webforms

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you can get this working with Web Forms without much trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is, and it's all in the box: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/879kf95c.aspx

Comment: the problem with asp.net membership system is , it is highly coupled with login controls and useless things. You see, i want to design login controls etc with textbox & others but provide only administration of roles and memberships to the admin & as far as i searched the product doesn't allow me to do the same.

Comment: @Deeptechtons It does. You just need to build your implementation on top of it.

Comment: @FrazellThomas you got a link or something to prove it?

Comment: @Deeptechtons Take a look @ MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx). You can call the underlying Membership class directly (say Membership.ValidateUser) to perform actions without using the built in controls.

Comment: @FrazellThomas sorry i wasn't clear `Do you know any role provider that would give me fine grain of control like above where i can edit roles for a membership, create new membership and assign roles` so my importance is about roles & membership rather than signup time integration

Comment: @Deeptechtons The built in membership support does support roles. As linked to in my previous comment via MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t32yf0a9.aspx). You can then build richer role support on top of it if needed, but the built in support seems adequate from your question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3784/discussion-between-frazell-thomas-and-deeptechtons)